# Writing logcat output to a file periodically via background service in Android

Tags: android

I want to write logcat results to a file in the background via a service. I have created a service and used the following code for having the logcat results.

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -d");
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
StringBuilder log = new StringBuilder();
String line;
while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            log.append(line);
}
```

Now with the above code, I am able to just write some of the logs only and if I remove the "-d" option then the service crashed.

Comment: Can you show us the crash?

Comment: @Tofasio hay now its not crashing but it only logging the logs of that application only not of the others... how to write the logs of the other application too........... -

Answer (score 0):

You have to have the phone rooted with priveleges R/W to that now.

Grant permissions to READ_LOGS on Manifest.xml.
Then write this code in OnCreate() of the Activity

```
String pname = getPackageName();
        String[] CMDLINE_GRANTPERMS = { "su", "-c", null };
        if (getPackageManager().checkPermission(android.Manifest.permission.READ_LOGS, pname) != 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "we do not have the READ_LOGS permission!");
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Working around JellyBeans 'feature'...");
                try {
                    // format the commandline parameter
                    CMDLINE_GRANTPERMS[2] = String.format("pm grant %s android.permission.READ_LOGS", pname);
                    java.lang.Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(CMDLINE_GRANTPERMS);
                    int res = p.waitFor();
                    Log.d(TAG, "exec returned: " + res);
                    if (res != 0)
                        throw new Exception("failed to become root");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "exec(): " + e);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed to obtain READ_LOGS permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        } else
            Log.d(TAG, "we have the READ_LOGS permission already!");
```

and then your code should work, run this instead if not

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c logcat D");
```